# Запуск видео ютуб с помощью джаваскрипт

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Есть встроенное видео ютуб на сайте, запускаю его через джаваскрипт, но после запуска видео мгновенно останавливается, я и посылал команду клика во фрейм, и ютуб api использовал, все одно и тоже, оно видео запускает, и через пол секунды его останавливает. Как это исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Имя, Сестра. В смысле, где код, который вы используете? Где минимальный воспроизводимый пример? Или вы думаете, что здесь спецы гадают на кофейной гуще? ))